# Swift 4 - 3D Touch Quick Actions With Tab Bar & Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, 3dtouch

I am trying to add 3D Touch Quick Actions from the home screen and I am using the following code:

```
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let tabVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabVC") as! UITabBarController
        let mainVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NavMoreVC") as! UINavigationController
        let foodVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FoodVC") as! FoodTableViewController
        window?.rootViewController = tabVC
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        mainVC.pushViewController(foodVC, animated: true)
```

I'm trying to navigate to the Find Food view controller after the user tapped on the shortcut, but the code above gives me an error in the console:

```
Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <UITabBarController: 0x10e022600>.
```

Is there a way for the app to push to the Find Food view controller while maintaining the Tab Bar and Navigation Controllers. Thanks!!

[image: Navigation Structure]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did some more digging and found the solution to it. I used the following code in the AppDelegate:

```
    let myTabBar = self.window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController
    myTabBar?.selectedIndex = 0
    let nvc = myTabBar?.selectedViewController as? UINavigationController
    let vc = nvc?.viewControllers.first as? MoreViewController
    nvc?.popToRootViewController(animated: false)
    return vc!.openPageFor(shortcutIdentifier: shortcutIdentifier)
```

Then inside my MoreViewController I had a function that will call the different segues based on the shortcutIdentifier.

Comment: I'm experiencing pretty much the exact same issue as in your OP, so I'm relieved to hear that you found a solution. How did you get your function in your MoreViewController to trigger segues based on the shortcutIdentifier?

Comment: I used a switch statement to perform the segue based on the shortcutIdentifier passed from the AppDelegate

Comment: awesome, that's what I essentially have set up so far, but I can't figure out how to pass any data from my AppDelegate to the necessary ViewController. I'm used to using destination = segue.destination --> destination.shortcutID = shortcutIdentifier inside of override func prepare(for segue:), but the several ways I've tried to pass the ID from my AppDelegate haven't worked. Did you use delegation or some other method?

Comment: I passed the identifier from the AppDelegate to the VC when calling the function. You shouldn't need prepare(for segue:) in AppDelegate, popToRootViewController(animated:) will do that for you. So all you have to do is pass the shortcutIdentifier in openPageFor(shortcutIdentifier) into the VC, then perform the segue inside the VC.

Comment: After a little bit of finagling, I got it to work! Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

First you make the rootVC as the tab then the navigate should be from inside it

so subclass the tabBarControllber and in viewDidAppear , do the push according to navigate bool or logic shared inside your app

```
    let foodVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FoodVC") as! BusStatusTableViewController
    // here do segue to food VC
```

Comment: Thanks! Turns out I had to do the segue in my More View Controller instead of doing everything in AppDelegate. I posted an answer to it that worked for me!